# Copy cell feature with complex object

Tags: angular, angular5, ag-grid

I am using complex object to render ag-grid column.

**Employee Name(street)**

John (st. lucy One)

John (st. lucy Two)

**For example this is json:**

```
  { 
      "employee":[
        "name": "John", 
        "address":[
           {
            "street":"st. lucy One",
            "postalcode":"jkjkjk"
             ....
           },
           {
            "street":"st. lucy Two",
            "postalcode":"jkjkjk"
             ....
           }
         ]
       ]
    }
```

**ag-grid column description:**

```
 {
        headerName: "Employee",
        field: "employee",
        cellRenderer: EmployeeComponent // Render HTML from component to display name & street in Employee Name(street) Column
 }
```

I am able to render HTML into cell.

**Problem:** However, it broke the feature of coping by right clicking on the Employee Name(street) cell. When I copy cell it copies Object [object] (which is I think is employee object) but not able to copy Employee Name(street) text.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide us a sample of code so that we could figure out? You have not specified any "feature of copying", so we cannot see what it looks like. Here you can make a sample of your question https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Hi Sergey, I have created an example here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-checkbox-eabwls


When you try to copy  "address one and address two"  by right clicking on the cell from "Employee Addresses" column and paste in notepad or anywhere. It copies object like [object Object],[object Object]....

Comment: It looks like you want to print there multiple addresses. Also I suppose that you are using a tool with built-in copy method to copy the contents of cell. That is the problem. You are pasting in a component not a text. You could just make `arr.join(' ')` to make a string of arrays values joined with specified symbol(s) and paste it in. Thus you would have a cell with a text inside not a component

Comment: Okay arr.join(‘ ‘) should work but where to implement this ? Do you know ag-grid function where i should write this statement ?

Comment: I don't. Actually you could join array then pass it to the directive. Thus you don't need a custom renderer

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this problem and I managed to get it working by using the code from this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56597441/3018671

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a valueGetter for the cell, you should have your problem gone.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-getters/

Hope this helps