# Copy Paste of Object in AgGrid not working

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

1. I have a created the AgGrid dataTable in which AgGrid Cell contians a custom object
2. The object has couple attributes like name, color, locked etc.
3. I am using customCellRenderer and customCellEditor
4. Now i am situation where i have to copy one cell data to other cell data.

I have tried the below methods exposed by AgGrid

```
 processCellFromClipboard = function(params) {
console.log(params.value);
return  params.value;}

  processCellForClipboard = function(params) {
    console.log(params.data);
    return  params.value;
  };
```

The FromClpboard method is giving object but i am not able the view the same in processCellFromCliboard.
Is there any other way i can implement the copy paste for the custom object. 
Any idea or sample will help up ?

> Currently evaulating AgGrid enterprise edition for the copy paste feasibility
>   of custom objects.

Answer (score 5):

```
// Copy and paste for objects is possible via the code below.
// Add these handlers to the gridOptions.

processCellFromClipboard: function(params) {
    return JSON.parse(params.value);
}

/**Method which copies for clipboard
* Method takes params which is given from agGrid
* Have to stringify the object as it will take only string
*/

processCellForClipboard: function(params) {
    return JSON.stringify(params.value);
}
```